# feign error handling by using feign decoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have **created service 'A', which needs to be calls by the service 'B' by using feign client**
And if service 'A' fails due to some validation, then service 'A' send back the error response which contains the below details,
**(1)http status code
(2)error message
(3) custom error map which contains the custom errorcode and their error message**
***for example, <"Emp-1001", "invalid employee Id">***

**From Service 'B' we are using feigndecoder for handling feign exception, but it only provides the http status code not the custom error code**

And, In my case, for different-different scenario, the http status code is same but custom error map value is different.
on the combination of both(http status code + custom error map), we  have to handle the exception in service 'B'.

kindly provide some suggestions on this

Comment: Could you add to your question with source code or more information?

Comment: We are using FeignErrorDecoder which implements ErrorDecode of feign and we are overriding decode  method(public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response)) where  from response we can able to only get the http status not custom errormap, mentioned in above

Comment: We got the solution and the solution as per below,

(1) you don't need a error decoder to handle the feign exception.
(2)you just need a exception handler which is accepting the FeignException
(3)From that FeignException, we can call the contentUtf8 method to get the whole custom exception response send by service 'A'.

Comment: Added the sample POC created on github

we have two service one is employee Service and another is feign service

From feignService we are calling the employee service and if employee service fails due to some error/exception and the same error response can be customized by feignService.
PFB repository details

https://github.com/agarwalsudhanshu46/employee
https://github.com/agarwalsudhanshu46/FeignService

Answer (score 1):

You can enable circuit breaker and also configure your application to apply different fallback methods depending on the error returned, follow the next steps:

1.- Enable the circuit breaker itself

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients("com.perritotutorials.feign.client")
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class FeignDemoClientApplication {
```

2.- Create your fallback bean

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class PetAdoptionClientFallbackBean implements PetAdoptionClient {
@Setter
    private Throwable cause;
@Override
    public void savePet(@RequestBody Map<String, ?> pet) {
        log.error("You are on fallback interface!!! - ERROR: {}", cause);
    }
}
```

Some things you must keep in mind for fallback implementations:

- Must be marked as @Component, they are unique across the application.
- Fallback bean should have a Prototype scope because we want a new one to be created for each exception.
- Use constructor injection for testing purposes.

3.- Your ErrorDecoder, to implement fallback startegies depending on the HTTP error returned:

```java
public class MyErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
private final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new Default();
@Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        if (response.status() >= 400 && response.status() <= 499) {
            return new MyCustomBadRequestException();
        }
if (response.status() >= 500) {
            return new RetryableException();
        }
        return defaultErrorDecoder.decode(methodKey, response);
    }
}
```

4.- In your configuration class, add the Retryer and the ErrorDecoder into the Spring context:

```java
@Bean
public MyErrorDecoder myErrorDecoder() {
  return new MyErrorDecoder();
}

@Bean
public Retryer retryer() {
    return new Retryer.Default();
}
```

You can also add customization to the Retryer:

```java
class CustomRetryer implements Retryer {
private final int maxAttempts;
    private final long backoff;
    int attempt;
public CustomRetryer() {
        this(2000, 5); //5 times, each 2 seconds
    }
public CustomRetryer(long backoff, int maxAttempts) {
        this.backoff = backoff;
        this.maxAttempts = maxAttempts;
        this.attempt = 1;
    }
public void continueOrPropagate(RetryableException e) {
        if (attempt++ >= maxAttempts) {
            throw e; 
        }
try {
            Thread.sleep(backoff);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
@Override
    public Retryer clone() {
        return new CustomRetryer(backoff, maxAttempts);
    }
}
```

If you want to get a functional example about how to implement Feign in your application, read [this](https://diego-rojas.medium.com/amazing-rest-clients-with-mr-feign-6195d5499a38) article.